# I can't install CTK (The Common Toolkit)

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying to install CTK but all times I try I get this error:

```
[ 41%] Built target CTKWidgetsPlugins
Scanning dependencies of target CTKWidgetsCppTests
[ 41%] Building CXX object Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/CMakeFiles/CTKWidgetsCppTests.dir/ctkSearchBoxTest1.cpp.o 

    /home/pedrojunior/Desktop/CTK/Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/ctkSearchBoxTest1.cpp: In function ‘int ctkSearchBoxTest1(int, char**)’:
            /home/pedrojunior/Desktop/CTK/Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/ctkSearchBoxTest1.cpp:43:24: error: ‘QPalette::ColorRole’ is not a class or namespace
p.setColor(QPalette::ColorRole::Window, Qt::gray);
                     ^
            /home/pedrojunior/Desktop/CTK/Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/ctkSearchBoxTest1.cpp:44:24: error: ‘QPalette::ColorRole’ is not a class or namespace
p.setColor(QPalette::ColorRole::Base, Qt::gray);
                     ^
make[5]: *** [Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/CMakeFiles/CTKWidgetsCppTests.dir/ctkSearchBoxTest1.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [Libs/Widgets/Testing/Cpp/CMakeFiles/CTKWidgetsCppTests.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CTK-prefix/src/CTK-stamp/CTK-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CTK.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 and I have installed cmake version 2.8.12.2 and Qt version 4.8.
Someone know how can I fix this error?

Comment: I just checked [CTK out from git](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Build_Instructions) and built it sucessfully using Qt 4.7.1, CMake 3.0.2 and GCC 4.8.2. What is your compiler version?

Comment: @m.s. The fix for the issue went into source on Apr 30 (https://github.com/commontk/CTK/pull/555), you will have the fix but the OP's distro hasn't picked it up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QPalette::ColorRole` is not a C++11 enum class, it's just a normal enum.  So the `ColorRole` part should not be declared.

Comment: Then, I should change and leave only "QPalette::Window"?

Comment: @PedroPaulo Yes, although it should be the library maintainer that fixes their code, there'a fix for it gone in: https://github.com/commontk/CTK/pull/555.  But your distro hasn't pulled in the latest version.